# Select from another mysql table

Tags: php, html, mysql

I would ask for any help, because Im desperate :D. I need help with my school project, where I have to save data from form. There´s one select, where should be dropdown with datas from another connected table.

here is screenshot of my relations:

[image]

```html
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
 $db = mysql_select_db("cznovis",$con);
 $get=mysql_query("SELECT id FROM listky);
$option = '';
 while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($get))
{
  $option .= '<option value = "'.$row['id'].'">'.$row['id'].'</option>';
}
?>
 <form action="odeslat.php" method="POST">
 <select name="typ">
<?php echo $option; ?>
</select>

 
 <input type="submit" name="odeslat" value="ODESLAT">
  </form>
```

i would appreciate any help

Comment: Look into using `join`s. Also you shouldn't use the `mysql_` functions anymore and this question has no actual relation to PHP. You are just trying to join two tables in mysql. It also would be better practice to make a `mysql` user for your web app rather than using the `root` user, and you should give your root user a password.

Comment: *"I need help with my school project"* i advice you to read [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Comment: I think there’s more to it than what you’re asking:  how are you determining which row of listky to use?  Because if you simply join the tables you’re going to get ALL options related to listky, not just the options for one record of listky. If you already know the id from listky then you only need to query ‘select * from clenstvi where typ=?’ (I’m showing this as a prepared statement)

Answer (score 1):

Simple usein  join should be enough.
Your query shoul by like this:

```
select * from clenstvi as cl join listky as li on cl.typ=listky.id;
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use left outer join in your query

```
select * from table1 left outer join table2 on table1.id = table2.id;
```

and then concatenate those two columns in your select

```
$row['data1'].$row['data2'];
```

Comment: Why left join?  It would work, but seems an inner join would be more appropriate